# ASP.net MVC Submit clear page cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CallRec objCallRec)
    {
                    // Add the record to the DB
        objCallRec.Add();

        ViewData["Message"] = MvcHtmlString.Create("(Your eference number for this lead is " + objCallRec.CustID + ")." + "<br />" + "<br />" + "Please close this browser.");
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("ThankYou");
    }
```

When the ThankYou is displayed and you refresh the page manully with F5 function key, lead gets entered into DB again. I get this prompt message:

To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.
If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click Retry to display the webpage again.

Is there a way to prevent this? I have used `ModelState.clear();` It did not prevent this.

Comment: Do it the correct way and redirect to a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have made a page level post back. However, instead of returning the view, you can redirect the user to another action result like the index page that thanks the user for the lead and they can take it up to wherever they would want to. Else, you can make an Ajax post so that the user saves and gets the partial view replaced in response.
The ajax method will be a preferred option if I had been to choose the right one for the job.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 return View("ThankYou");
```

Try

```
 return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
```

return View("Thankyou")  tells MVC to generate HTML to be displayed for the specified view and sends it to the browser. This acts like as Server.Transfer() in Asp.Net WebForm.

whereas in RedirecToAction, browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified action. This acts like as Response.Redirect()

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.